# How to kill and restart processes within a pexpect child process?

Tags: python, ssh, spawn, pexpect

I can currently spawn an SSH connection with `pexpect` and from within that SSH connection start another process (`my_app`). Like so:

```
child = pexpect.spawn('ssh user@example.com')
# ... handle connection details ...
child.sendline('./my_app')
# ... interact with my_app ...
```

This all works fine. However, I'd like to be able to kill `my_app` and restart it, if needed. I was able to do it by starting `my_app` in the background (`./my_app &`), saving the PID to a variable, sending `CTRL-Z`, and issuing the kill command, but this has been flaky in many ways.

Is there another, more correct/stable way to do this?

Comment: how do you know when to kill the app?

Comment: Once certain criteria have been met, usually at the end of a series of steps, but since I may be in different states of the app, it will be easier to kill it, than to try and figure out a generic way of resetting it to the initial state.

Answer (score 0):

## For killing the child process(pexpect) we can use close()

```
child = pexpect.spawn('ssh user@example.com')

child.close()
```

### for restarting can use spawn again

Please refer [pexpect — Spawn child applications and control them automatically](http://www.bx.psu.edu/%7Enate/pexpect/pexpect.html#pexpect.spawn.close)

Comment: This would close the connection to the entire `child` process and all its children, but I'd like to be able to terminate only `my_app`, which itself is a child of `child` process.